# Adjusting weights in meta-analyses using R

Tags: r, meta-analysis, weights

I am conducting a meta-analysis in R. Some of my studies provide more than one effect size for the same sample.

I would like to account for this by adjusting the weight that each within-study effect size receives, so that studies with multiple effect sizes don't receive more weight than they should and so that the weight is evenly shared within studies.

My first thought is to simply divide the variances by the appropriate number (e.g., if I have 3 within-study effect sizes: divide each variance by 3), then enter those values into the analysis. But I am unsure if that is the best way to go about the process, or if there are functions that I am unaware of...

How would you all suggest I might go about adjusting the weights?

Comment: The key search term you are looking for is multi-level meta-analysis in R, This is only a comment as requests for programming help are off-topic here but the search will turn up loads of suggestions.